# Question about if $g\circ f$ is surjective then $g$ is surjective.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Suppose we have $f:A\rightarrow B$ and $g:B\rightarrow C$

if $g\circ f$ is surjective then $g$ is surjective.

This seems one directional as in $\Rightarrow$, but my Professor said if it is a definition then it is always an $\iff$ no matter how the statement is said (or that is how I am interpreting his words, correct me if I am wrong!)

Proof:

Let $c\in C$ be arbritrary. Given that $g\circ f$ is surjective, there exists an $a\in A$ such that $g\circ f(a)= g(f(a))=c$. This implies we have some $b=f(a)\in B$ such that $g(b)= c$. Hence we have shown $g$ is surjective.

But I am wondering is it necessarily true if we try to prove the backwards direction? I seem to run into the problem that I am uncertain if $B$ in $f$ is the same $B$ in $g$.

Comment: It is certainly possible to have $g$ surjective without $g\circ f$ being surjective. One example is $f=const$. Do I understand correctly that this is your question?

Comment: No I meant that if we tried to show the converse of the statement that is if $g$ is surjective then $g\circ f$ is surjective but I think the answer below helped me out!

Comment: It is true that usually in definitions we simply say "if" when we really mean "if and only if". For example "a function $f:X\to X$ is happy if $f=\text{id}_X$". Here, I am defining the term "happy", and I have simply used the conditional "if", as opposed to the more correct "if and only if", because that is just how we speak. However the statement "if $g\circ f$ is surjective then $g$ is surjective" is NOT a definition. This is a theorem, and in theorems, we are always careful to distinguish between "if", "only if" and "if and only if".

Comment: @peek-a-boo I see is it safe to say every definition is an iff statement and its possible that some Theorem is one directional?  I believe someone once told me on here that there are no 'definitions' in math only theorems.  Would axioms and postulates be considered definitions?  Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, every definition is really an "iff" even though we say "if". Theorems are always very careful, it is possible to be one directional $\implies$, $\impliedby$ without being bi-directional $\iff$. Well, whoever told you that must have said so in a very specific context. Anyway, the other questions you should really ask a separate question to clarify all the terminology. Sometimes, you may even see $:\iff$ to mean "by definition", or stuff like $:=$ to mean "equal by definition".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is correct.  The converse is not true.  For example, $g: \{1,2\} \rightarrow \{1,2\}, 1 \mapsto 1, 2\mapsto 2$ is surjective, but if $f: \{1\} \rightarrow \{1\}$ is defined by $1 \mapsto 1$ then $g \circ f$ is not surjective.

Probably what your professor meant was that when we define something, we sometimes use "if" and let "only if" be implied. e.g.,

> We say that $f:A\rightarrow B$ is *surjective* if for all $b \in B$ there exists some $a \in A$ with $f(a) = b$.

This is a definition, so really "if" means "if and only if".  The reason is that a definition *must* be an "if and only if" condition to be sensible; otherwise it is ill-defined.  Context clues tell you it is a definition: the use of "we say that" and italics around the term *surjective* (and perhaps that the term has not been used before in the text.)  In your case, the statement is *not* a definition, so the converse is not implied.

Comment: Thank you so much this was very insightful!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

The backwards direction isn't true in general. Here's a counter example.

let $A=B=C=\mathbb{R}$

let $f(x)=1$.

let $g(x)=x$.

$g(x)$ is surjective.

$f(g(x)) = 1$ which is not surjective

There must have been something he said wrong, or you misunderstood.

EDIT: I agree with peek-a-boo. Is it possible he was describing 'if and only if"? "if and only if" does correspond to definitions.